# How to replace an ASUS C523NA-IH24T Chromebook screen?

Tags: laptop-repair, chromebook, repair

I have the ASUS C523NA-IH24T and I ordered a replacement screen from [this place](https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/model/ASUS/CHROMEBOOK%7EC523NA-IH24T/) and I have received the screen and am trying to put it on.

I have the cracked screen detached from the Chromebook base, but I am not sure how to remove the broken screen to replace with the new one? I have tried to wedge a pry tool under all areas of the screen itself to pry it loose, but nothing is working.

I'm starting to think, I may have to replace the entire top panel of this Chromebook, however when I Google around for that, I don't see it as an option so I must be missing something here.

How do I dissasemble this piece so I can attach my replacement screen?

[image]

Comment: The answer in this case is clearly that the original poster is in over their heads, when they say: “I'm starting to think, I may have to replace the entire top panel of this Chromebook…” Yes, that is the case. The screen is most likely just glued in place and simply “swapping it out” is not an option.

Comment: I posted an answer on how to unglue, separate and replace, but it was downvoted out of existence.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - i didn't realize this model chromebook was that way.  I know some you can swap out the screen no issue.

Comment: @John “I posted an answer on how to unglue, separate and replace, but it was downvoted out of existence.” Stop lying. It was downvoted exactly once (by me) and flagged as not an answer since it was not only a link only answer but it was an answer focused on removing iPad 5th Gen screens. As I have said in the past you often post comments as answers and then quickly delete the second you are caught. Try to spend some time to actually provide a real answer and guess what? Your rushed answers do not get downvoted. You clearly have knowledge; just adjust your speed of posting.

Comment: These devices mostly have screens glued on so the article I posted shows clearly how to replace glued on screens. Very difficult in nature but it can be done. I was in no way rushing. I have used this Blog’s videos before and I know what I am looking at.

Comment: It looks like digitizers for these are available on AliExpress. I just ordered one and will see how the replacement goes at some future time. Certainly not as easy as your standard student Chromebooks.

Comment: Is this a touchscreen model? Then the display itself is probably not what needs replacement at all, but instead the digitizer.

Answer (score 0):

From experience with an Asus C434T which I bought from Ebay a few months ago which must have had a poorly executed screen replacement I can say that this generation of devices has glued in screens. They can be replaced, I think it's done by warming up the screen on one side with what [iFixit call an iOpener](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/iOpener/IF145-198). They then usually use [suction cups](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/iSclack/IF145-243) to separate the screen from the base. So you will at least need these tools or similar tools I think. You should watch some of their tear down videos to understand what they are doing to repair devices. iFixit claim they have a wide range of articles for different devices and a great community, but I find it unintuitive to find resources to explain something in an answer like here.

Further you will need double sided sticky repair tape to glue the new screen in place. I wasn't satisfied with the result of mine. The screen did become loose again on the sides when opening the laptop even though I used as much tape as possible and let it settle with 2 tetra paks of milk as weight for a few days. I finally decided to use [Pattex Repair 100%¹](https://www.amazon.de/Pattex-100-Allesklebe/dp/B079MFGRSG), a not(!) cyanoacrylate-based glue to fix the sides. This seems to be a stronger glue than the sticky tape I bought and should be used sparingly. You want to use just the right amount to not have excess protrude through the gaps onto your screen. It's kind of gummy and removable, but it will be quite a hassle. Sorry I did not take photos back then. You will notice that your new screen, like mine has edges which are not display area Asus does not glue these to the base. This is probably so that technicians have room to insert prying tools for repairs. You may be lucky and will find that you can insert prying tools at the bottom to work your way around the screen. As I said I used a bit of glue to fix the sides even though Asus did not use glue there.

[image: prying tool inserted at the bottom of a C434T screen]

Best would be to get advice and borrow tools from one of the repair shops near you. They can better advise you what you can try and what you should not. At least I hope they are more competent than me.

Edit: Don't forget that you have a camera module there! Be slow and careful around that area.

1: It looks like you cannot find this outside of Europe or in English speaking countries. This glue is based on [N-[3-(Trimethoxysilyl)propyl]ethylenediamine](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/ALDRICH/104884?lang=en&region=US). A simply unreadable name.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I have a prying tool, heat gun and multiple suction cups so if seperating it is what needs to occur I can do it.  But what is the piece called that I need to replace?  I thought it was the screen, but I found out that is what is inside of the glass that is cracked and I read I actually needed the digitizer which I have not been able to find online anywhere.

Comment: Sorry that is beyond my experience. I replaced a screen before, but never had to dig deeper.